# Grails sort map by key

Tags: grails

Hi am trying to sort a map using the map's key

```
finalMap.entrySet().sort{it.key}
```

But the key is not sorted as follows:

```
[0=org.generator.Item@1304e60, 1=org.generator.Item@699df5, 10=org.generator.Item@14944, 11=org.generator.Item@713a72, 12=org.generator.Item@1b42301, 2=org.generator.Item@1664cde, 3=org.generator.Item@1409c28, 4=org.generator.Item@cc2061, 5=org.generator.Item@161eccb, 6=org.generator.Item@13e9b, 7=org.generator.Item@1b5438d, 8=org.generator.Item@1661f7b, 9=org.generator.Item@19cf00a]
```

Comment: It looks sorted, but in lexicographical order. http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/lexicgrphcl.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
finalMap.entrySet().sort{it.key as Integer}
```